# ReadFile and Split info

Tags: java, split, readfile

This is my question.

```
    (f)Define a method, public String toString(),  that returns a String consisting of the Student object’s admin number, name and average score.

    (h)Define another constructor with the method signature Student(String studentRecord),where studentRecord is of the format given below:   adminNo;name;day/month/year;test1;test2;test3 birthdate
       Example of a given string: 031234F;Michael Tan;01/08/1980;60;70;98

    (i)Break up studentRecord into its constituent elements and use them to initialise the class variables, adminNo, name, birthdate, test1, test2, test3.

    (i) Define a main() method to read a single record from the "student.txt" and **display the admin number, name and average score of the student.**
```

And here are my code :

```
    public class Student {

String adminNo;
String name;
GregorianCalendar birthDate;
int test1,test2,test3;

public Student(String adminNo,String name,String birthDate,int test1, int test2, int test3){
    this.adminNo = adminNo;
    this.name = name;
    this.birthDate = MyCalendar.convertDate(birthDate);
    this.test1 = test1;
    this.test2 = test2;
    this.test3 = test3;
}

public Student(String studentRecord){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(studentRecord);
    sc.useDelimiter(";");
    adminNo = sc.next();
    name = sc.next();
    birthDate = MyCalendar.convertDate(birthDate.toString());
    test1 = sc.nextInt();
    test2 = sc.nextInt();
    test3 = sc.nextInt();
}

public int getAverage(){ 
    return (( test1 + test2 + test3 ) / 3 ) ;
}

public String toString(){
    return (adminNo + " " + name + " " + getAverage());
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    Student s = new Student ("121212A", "Tan Ah Bee", "12/12/92", 67, 72, 79);
    System.out.println(s);

    String fileName = "student.txt";
    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }

        fr.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
        System.out.println("File " + fileName + " was not found");
    }catch(IOException exception){
        System.out.println(exception);
    }
}
```

And this is the format of info int text file :

```
    031234F;Michael Tan;01/08/1980;60;70;98
```

I managed to print out :

```
    121212A Tan Ah Bee 72
    031234F;Michael Tan;01/08/1980;60;70;98
    123456J;Abby;12/12/1994;67;78;89
```

But this is what the question wants :

```
    121212A Tan Ah Bee 72
    031234F Michael Tan 72
    123456J Abby 72
```

Am I missing something? I only know that's the toString() method but I do not know how to place it within the while loop.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not need to print the line you just read (unless you do it for debugging purposes).  You need to feed this line into your **Constructor** and then print the result of your `toString` method for this newly created instance.

Comment: But I thought sc.nextLine is equals to studentRecord and therefore, the system will use that constructor automatically to split the info? And am I supposed to use the toString method in main method? Can you please kindly give me some example?

Comment: I've modified my code to this : while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    Student student = new Student(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println(student.toString());} But there's null pointer exception error. Am I going to the wrong path?

Comment: What is the line `NullPointerException` is pointing to?

Comment: Student stud = new Student that line and birthDate = MyCalendar.convertDate(birthDate.toString()); which is in the constructor with a String parameter

Comment: You have `GregorianCalendar birthDate;`. But then you somehow decide that it's a String. In this statement your call `toString` method when birtDate is **null**.`birthDate = MyCalendar.convertDate(birthDate.toString());`

Comment: so how am I supposed to do to convert my GregorianCalendar into String without crashing the toString method? Because there is a convertDate method in another class which take in String and return GregorianCalendar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28484/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-rauryn)

Comment: Thanks PM 77-1. Its solved already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
}
```

You seem to need:

```
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        Student stu = new Student(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println(stu.toString());
    }
```

The above code will invoke **constructor** for class `Student` which will split the line and populate its fields.  Then your toString() method will create an output string in the specified format.

Comment: I tested it out already, as from the posts above but it gives me null pointer exception error.

Comment: As I already requested, please see which statement your `NullPointerException` is pointing to.